# Use supportFragmentManager inside CustomView inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have 2 fragments: MainGameFragment and PostGameFragment

When MainActivity gets Launched it goes to MainGameFragment where i have a CustomView with an animation(it would be a game).

Inside the CustomView i check every frame if the player loses, when he loses i call a method.

I need to change to PostGameFragment from inside the CustomView when the player loses and the method is called.

How can i do that?

I tried using supportFragmentManager but i get this: Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager

Here i my GameFragment code, gameView is the ID of the CustomView that is inside GameFrament and Game is the class for the gameView where i have the onDraw method and the onLoseListener.

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class GameFragment : Fragment() {
private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null
private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)

    }
}

override fun onCreateView(

    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false)

    gameView.onLoseListener = {
        println("Testing..")
    }

    // Return the fragment view/layout
    return view

}

fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
    listener?.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        listener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
    }
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    listener = null
}


interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)

}
companion object {       
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() =
        GameFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {

            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to access the fragment manger from inside the view. I think it would be better to have a sort of `onLoseListener` function in your custom view, just like the standard `onClickListener` so that the fragment knows when the "lose" event happens and can act accordingly

Comment: ohh, that makes sense, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical pattern is to add a callback (listener) to your `View` that you `invoke` from inside, to signal the event to the code outside.

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context?,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    var onLoseListener: () -> Unit = {
        // do nothing by default
    }

    // to signal the listener call -> `onLoseListener.invoke()`
}
```

Wherever you have your `CustomView`:

```
class CustomFragment : Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //... inflate

        // assuming you have `val customView : CustomView`
        // setting up the listener:
        customView.onLoseListener = {
            //do something on the listener being invoked by the CustomView
        }
        return yourInflatedLayout
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and updated the post with code, it gives me an error in GameFragment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.myapplication.Game.setOnLoseListener(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.GameFragment.onCreateView(GameFragment.kt:55)

Comment: `// assuming you have val customView : CustomView`
Did you set up your `customView`?

Comment: Sorry im starting to learn Android, i dont uderstand what you mean by this, do you mean like this? Game is the Class of my customView    `lateinit var customView : Game`

Comment: ok, first you have to set up your `customView` with something like `view.findViewById` (depending how you get instances of your `Views` in your code)